# JetBrainsのIDEで日本語が指定した行幅で折り返されない

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

確認環境
Windows10 64bit
IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2

`File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Right margin`から自動折り返しの行幅を設定できますが、コメント等、日本語を使用する部分ではこの設定が効きません。
日本語は1文字が2文字幅でカウントして折り返しをしてくれるのが理想なのですが、そういった設定はできないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

全角文字の幅の計算が間違っているの既知の問題として以下に登録されております。
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-150985

残念ながら現在のところ修正の予定は立っていません。
ログインしてvote(親指を立てているアイコンをクリック)することで修正を促すことが可能です。